# MySQL - Selecting people's names based on most occurrences

Tags: mysql

Given:

Table called `names` with `id`, `first` and `last` fields.

How would you find the top 5 most popular people by occurrence when the `first` and `last` are separate fields? This is the non-working code I have now...

```
`SELECT *, COUNT(first) AS occurrences FROM `names` GROUP BY first ORDER BY occurrences DESC LIMIT 5`
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: What do you mean by `name and value are separate fields`?

Comment: When you say "non-working code", does that mean you get an error or just the wrong results?

Comment: "\`" delineates inline [code](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks). For blocks of code, indent the lines an extra four spaces. You can also use "\" to escape special characters to make them ordinary. Example: `SELECT * FROM \`foo\``. As explaining things, [concise code samples](http://sscce.org/) are often the least ambiguous way. Please show your table schema (`CREATE` statements).

Comment: @kakao, @outis - reformatted question, thanks. @galz - i didn't even run it, it's conceptually close but not what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

For top 5 first names, try:

```
SELECT first, COUNT(*) AS occurrences 
FROM names
GROUP BY first 
ORDER BY occurrences DESC 
LIMIT 5
```

For top 5 names, try:

```
SELECT first, last, COUNT(*) AS occurrences 
FROM names
GROUP BY first, last
ORDER BY occurrences DESC 
LIMIT 5
```

Comment: Or, to get the name as one field in the result: select distinct concat_ws(' ', first, last) as name, count(*) as num from names group by name order by num desc limit 5;

Comment: Man, this worked perfectly. I was struggling with a query myself until I found this.